# Error in Bazel build

Tags: android, android-ndk, tensorflow, bazel

While building tensor-flow demo for Android, I get the following error:

error loading package 'external': The repository named 'inception5h' could not be resolved and referenced by '//tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo'.

Can anyone help?`Here is my Workspace:
android_sdk_repository(
    name = "androidsdk",
    api_level = 23,
    build_tools_version = "23.0.1",
    # Replace with path to Android SDK on your system
    path = "/home/aamir/Android/Sdk/",
)
android_ndk_repository(
    name="androidndk",
    path="/home/aamir/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle",
    api_level=21)`

Comment: Did you run blaze fetch?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define inception5h in your WORKSPACE file, specifically add [these lines](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/WORKSPACE#L25-L30).

However, you should really just copy that entire file into your WORKSPACE file.  Bazel will only download things that are required to build the Android demo, and that way you don't have to worry about missing repo definitions.